# VideoSDK api don't use updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, videosdk.live

I'm using React + ASP.NET application and using VideoSDK API for video-meeting.

```
const meetingAPI = useMeeting({
onMeetingJoined: () => {
      meetinAPI.muteMic();
      meetinAPI.disableWebcam();
      if (isCreator) {
        let intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
          console.log(
            "minutes",
            minutes +
              gameHash.ActivePlayers.length
          );
          if (
            minutes + gameHash.ActivePlayers.length >= asset.VideoTime - 10 * ActivePlayers.length
          ) {
            setVideoMinutesRunoutModalOpen(true);
          }
        }, 1000 * 60);
        setTimerId(intervalId);
      }
      setIsMeetingJoined(true);
    },
})
```

isCreator and gameHash is component state.
When it changed, I expect value in onMeetingJoined change too.
But it's always the initial value.
How can I solve this?

I've tried to use useCallback or useMemo.
But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced same issue before.
And their support team was so helpful.
You can use state ref for that.

```
const stateRef = useRef();
stateRef.current = {
  minutes: minutes,
  gameHash: gameHash
};

onMeetingJoined: () => {
      meetinAPI.muteMic();
      meetinAPI.disableWebcam();
      if (stateRef.current.isCreator) {
        let intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
          console.log(
            "minutes",
            stateRef.current.minutes +
              stateRef.current.gameHash.ActivePlayers.length
          );
          if (
            stateRef.current.minutes +
              stateRef.current.gameHash.ActivePlayers.length >=
            stateRef.current.asset.VideoTime -
              10 * stateRef.current.gameHash.ActivePlayers.length
          ) {
            setVideoMinutesRunoutModalOpen(true);
          }
        }, 1000 * 60);
        setTimerId(intervalId);
      }
      setIsMeetingJoined(true);
    },
```

As you can see, stateRef is reference for your state.
onMeetingJoined is a third party callback so your state change is not reflected.
And this is the solution.

Comment: should I use useCallback for onMeetingJoined?

Comment: no.
just use that code.
no need to do that.

Comment: do you know about videosdk billing?